# Issues in flash site coversion using createJS to HTML5 to get it working in android devices

Tags: android, html, flash, createjs

We have 100s of flash files in our site. Multiple swf files uses AS3 and xml files for flash movies .
We have converted .fla files to HTML5 using createJS.
We are getting following errors for some of flash files during export to HTML5 and not converting.

- an unexpected error occurred during export. (JSK)

Converted html5 files are not working same as flash. 
Our approach was

- to covert the flash file in to HTML5 using tools
- Editing the coverted code and use the help of java script library, try to make it as working like  flash.

We are struck with this approach because we are not getting proper html5 code for the most of files.
We had chosen createJS (conversion tool) because the converted code is readable.

Below are my doubts

1. Is our approach correct?
2. We are targeting high resolution android tablets. So while doing it, do we need to take 
   care any import things like screen resolution , scaling etc ?
3. Is there is any other workaround solution to convert flash site to android tablet compatible?

**Note** : We have tried swiffy but swiffy does not support AS3 and converted code is not readable too!

Answer (score 0):

The CreateJS tool can help you convert your flash assets and scripts to HTML5 with javascript, but you will almost always have little issues to handle on a case-by-case basis. Especially if you have lots of actionscript, complex animations within animations, or audio and video players, you will have to rewrite some of your code.

Also, CreateJS does not automatically make your animation responsive to different screen sizes or create retina assets.

CreateJS works best if you know beforehand that your flash animation will be converted to HTML5. Then you can take into account the things that work, and those that won't.